# Variable is not defined even though it is?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, http

Hi I'm trying to call a php function when a button is pressed but I keep getting the error in the title.

I'm calling the function like so:

```
echo("<th><input type='button' name = 'Attack_Btn' onclick = 'FightPlayer(".$row['username'].")' value ='Attack'></th>");
```

just say the username that it gets from $row['user... is James the error will display

index.php:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: casualjames is not defined

This is the code that it calls next

```
    function FightPlayer(enemyName){
    var xhttpe;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhttpe = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
        xhttpe = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhttpe.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            BattlePlayers();
        }
    };
    xhttpe.open("GET", "FightPlayer.php?enemyname="+enemyName, true);
    xhttpe.send();
}
```

and then it calls my php script passing in the variable `enemyname` for it to use

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    include 'Training.php';
    $link = mysqli_connect("","","","");

    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        $enemyname = $_REQUEST["enemyname"];
        echo $enemyname;
        $energyRemove = 1;
        $ExperienceGain = 1;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM userstats WHERE username = '$enemyname'";
        $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $Defence = $row["Defence"];
        $winChance = CalculateWinChance($link,$Defence);
        $sql = "SELECT Energy FROM userstats WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $rand = rand ( 1 , 100 );
        if($row["Energy"] < 1 ){
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Not enough energy to fight. please restore in character page');</script>";
        }else{
            if($rand < $winChance){
                $_SESSION['Battlemessage'] = "you won against ".$enemyname;
                $sql = "UPDATE userstats SET `Energy` = `Energy` - '$energyRemove' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";
                mysqli_query($link,$sql);
                $sql = "UPDATE userstats SET `Experience` = `Experience` + '$ExperienceGain' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";
                mysqli_query($link,$sql);
                $sql = "UPDATE userstats SET `Satoshi` = `Satoshi` + 2 WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";
                mysqli_query($link,$sql);
            }else{
                $_SESSION['Battlemessage'] = "you lost against ".$enemyname;
                $sql = "UPDATE userstats SET `Energy` = `Energy` - '$energyRemove' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";
                mysqli_query($link,$sql);
                $sql = "UPDATE userstats SET `Satoshi` = `Satoshi` + 1 WHERE username = '".$enemyname."'";
                mysqli_query($link,$sql);
            }
            echo "";
        }
        calculateLevel($link);
    }
?>
```

I'm not sure where the error is actually happening I've put my scripts through online code checkers and it all returns normal. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: On a side note - This code is all setup for a 'Stored XSS attacks' you got your non sanitized input being injected into the database, and then you got it ($enemyname) being output to other users with no escaping.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix oh i was under the impression you only needed to do that for input fields?

Comment: It's best to always do that, especially when you are saving things in the session, you could accidentally allow input into a parameter that you though would be safe when you wrote this code.  It's also best to use htmlentities on anything you output to a browser ( that's not supposed to contain html ) that might interpret embedded javascript.  The idea is to protect it right at the point it would fail.  So queries, just before doing insert, update, select etc. and output just before it's output.  Then you wont worry latter if you change some code, that affects it.

Comment: Stored XSS attacks are ( typically ) where you save some malicious JS in your database and then output it to your other users.  Which allows session hijacking and all kinds of nastiness. Just because something comes out of the session doesn't mean it was safe going in.  You could allow some text that contains JS, the DB wont care to much about this, it's just text to it.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix interesting thanks for the info. when i first launched my site some of my friends put alerts as there user names that was rather funny :P if your interested this is the site im making bitcoinrpg.com. its mainly for a learning proccess im making everything from scratch so i can show that ive learnt everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string you're passing into your javascript function needs to be quoted, or else it thinks that it's a variable:

```
echo("<th><input type='button' name = 'Attack_Btn' onclick = 'FightPlayer(\"".$row['username']."\")' value ='Attack'></th>");
```

Answer (score 3):

Your error is most likely with the onclick...you need to escape quotes in the function argument here:

```
echo("<th><input type='button' name = 'Attack_Btn' onclick = 'FightPlayer(\"".$row['username']."\")' value ='Attack'></th>");
```